# Subprocess to run lftp on Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to write a sub-process to do an `lftp` (bash command `lftp`) in Python. It works perfectly in Python 2.7 but fails in Python 3.6

**Working code in Python 2.7**

```
>>> uname = 'bunnylorr@gmail.com'
>>> pass_wrd = '*********'
>>> flink = 'ftps://ftp.filestorage.com:990'
>>> src_dir = 'Acct\ Files'
>>> src_frmt = 'compact_'
>>> import subprocess
>>> cmd = """
... filelist=$(lftp -c "open -u {usr},{pwd} {url};cd {sdir};cls -1| grep {sname}")
...         echo "INFO: List of files to download: \n$filelist \n"
...         for file in $filelist; do lftp -c "open -u {usr},{pwd} {url};cd {sdir};get $file"; \
...         echo "INFO: File downloaded to local -  $file \n"; done """ \
...         .format(usr = uname, pwd = pass_wrd, url = flink, sdir = src_dir, sname = src_frmt )

>>> ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT); cmd_opt = ps.communicate()[0]
>>> print(cmd_opt)
```

Output Received:

```
INFO: List of files to download: 
compact_wizard_20201211.csv
compact_accounts_20201211.csv
compact_register_20201211.csv 

INFO: File downloaded to local -  compact_wizard_20201211.csv 

INFO: File downloaded to local -  compact_accounts_20201211.csv

INFO: File downloaded to local -  compact_register_20201211.csv
```

**However I tried the same code on python 3.6 I get the below error**

```
>>> uname = 'bunnylorr@gmail.com'
>>> pass_wrd = '*********'
>>> flink = 'ftps://ftp.filestorage.com:990'
>>> src_dir = 'Acct\ Files'
>>> src_frmt = 'compact_'
>>> import subprocess
>>> cmd = """
... filelist=$(lftp -c "open -u {usr},{pwd} {url};cd {sdir};cls -1| grep {sname}")
...         echo "INFO: List of files to download: \n$filelist \n"
...         for file in $filelist; do lftp -c "open -u {usr},{pwd} {url};cd {sdir};get $file"; \
...         echo "INFO: File downloaded to local -  $file \n"; done """ \
...         .format(usr = uname, pwd = pass_wrd, url = flink, sdir = src_dir, sname = src_frmt )

>>> ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT); cmd_opt = ps.communicate()[0]
>>> print(cmd_opt)
```

Error: `b'/bin/sh: lftp: command not found\n'`

Any recommendations or suggestions on this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed lftp on my server and reran the Python cmd. It worked!!

```
sudo apt-get install lftp
```